# how To manage middleware to redirect different users in there own dashboard using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do that when what type of users login its redirect to it own dashboard. User and SuperAdmin is okay when login but when i am login with branchAdmin account it not redirct to branch dashboard, it redirect to the user dashboard. And with branchAdmin contants. What i do.

Routes:

```
    Route::group(['middleware'  =>  [ 'auth', 'isAdmin']], function(){
        Route::get('/profile','ProfileController@getIndex');
    });

    Route::group(['middleware'  =>  [ 'auth', 'isBranchAdmin']], function(){
        Route::get('/branch','BranchController@gettIndex');
    });

    Route::group(['middleware'  =>  [ 'auth', 'isNotAdmin']], function(){
    Route::get('/Super/admin', 'AdminController@getIndex');
        });
```

View:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->type === 'User')
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li role="presentation" class="active">
                <a id="bootstrap-overrides" href="/home">
                    Home
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a id="bootstrap-overrides" href="/contact">
                    Contact
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a id="bootstrap-overrides" href="/about">
                    About
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a id="bootstrap-overrides" href="/blog">
                    Blog
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a id="bootstrap-overrides" href="/faqs">
                    FAQs
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    @elseif(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->type === 'Admin')
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li role="presentation" @if(Request::path() === 'companies') class="active" @endif>
                <a href="/companies">
                    Companies
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" @if(Request::path() === 'branchies') class="active" @endif>
                <a href="/branchies">
                    Branchies
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    @elseif(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->type === 'BranchAdmin')
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li role="presentation" @if(Request::path() === 'medicines') class="active" @endif>
                <a href="/medicines">
                    Medicines
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" @if(Request::path() === 'stock') class="active" @endif>
                <a href="/stock">
                    Stock_details
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    @endif
</div>
```

Middleware:

BranchAdmin

```
class BranchAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next){
        if(Auth::user()->type === 'BranchAdmin'){
            return redirect('/branch');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

UserIsAdmin:

```
class UserIsAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->type === 'Admin'){
            return redirect('/Super/admin');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

UserIsNotAdmin:

```
class UserIsNotAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->type === 'User'){
            return redirect('/profile');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: share your middlewares too. And also you should check isAdmin to redirect admin, isUser to user. isBranch to go branch but currently you check isNotAdmin to redirect Admin. its a mistake and kills code readability.

Comment: You are right but first time when i do this that you told me its not redirect right way. And when i replace this body's its redirect right.

Answer (score 2):

Solution fo Laravel 5.* Go to the Login Controller:

```
app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php
```

Find and edit method:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
  {
    // Do something with user
    // redirect user to dashboard
  }
```